# Почему не считывается файл?

Tags: c++

Есть файл со следующим содержанием текста:

> |..|............|............|
>
> |..|U...........|............|
>
> |..|...R........|............|

Между строками одинарный перенос, а не двойной. Я просто не знаю, как его правильно вставить, чтобы было, как в блокноте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
.

Необходимо считать вот эту часть в каждой строке.

> "U...........|............|"

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

char PowerReset[4];
char Up1[1],Down1[1],Left1[1],Right1[1],A1[1],B1[1],C1[1],S1[1],X1[1],Y1[1],Z1[1],M1[2];
char Up2[1],Down2[1],Left2[1],Right2[1],A2[1],B2[1],C2[1],S2[1],X2[1],Y2[1],Z2[1],M2[2];
string g = ""; 


int main()
{
    ifstream read1("D:\\Input_Log.txt");
    if (!read1.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Failed to open a file!" << endl;
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
    while(!read1.eof())
    {
        read1.getline(PowerReset, 4 /*,'|'*/);
        read1.getline(Up1, 1);
        read1.getline(Down1, 1);
        read1.getline(Left1, 1);
        read1.getline(Right1, 1);
        read1.getline(A1, 1);
        read1.getline(B1, 1);
        read1.getline(C1, 1);
        read1.getline(S1, 1);
        read1.getline(X1, 1);
        read1.getline(Y1, 1);
        read1.getline(Z1, 1);
        read1.getline(M1, 2);
        read1.getline(Up2, 1);
        read1.getline(Down2, 1);
        read1.getline(Left2, 1);
        read1.getline(Right2, 1);
        read1.getline(A2, 1);
        read1.getline(B2, 1);
        read1.getline(C2, 1);
        read1.getline(S2, 1);
        read1.getline(X2, 1);
        read1.getline(Y2, 1);
        read1.getline(Z2, 1);
        read1.getline(M2, 2);

        if (*S1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*C1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*B1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*A1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Right1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Left1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Down1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Up1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*S2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*C2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*B2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*A2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Right2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Left2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Down2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Up2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*M2 == '.')
        g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Z2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Y2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*X2 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*M1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Z1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*Y1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';

        if (*X1 == '.')
            g += '0'; 
        else g += '1';
        //cout << Up1 << Down1 << Left1 << Right1 << A1 << B1 << C1 << S1 << X1 << Y1 << Z1 << M1;
    }
    read1.close();
    //cout << g << endl; //отсутствует операнд "<<" (перед g), соответствующий этим операндам

    return 0;
}
```

Код ужасен, спору нет, но я уже локти кусаю, т.к. не могу понять, почему цикл while не работает. Почему?

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: @VTT Видимо, какая-то ошибка чтения. Я ничего не могу вывести на консоль и вообще удостовериться, что я на верном пути. Нигде не в цикле, не после него не работает cout.

Comment: Ну так а вы можете конкретно написать, что происходит? Вот зашли в цикл, выполняете первый `read1.getline(PowerReset, 4 /*,'|'*/);` - он выполняется или нет? Строка считывается или нет? и на каком месте оно перестает работать как надо

Comment: @YTT Вот перед этой строчкой или во время её выполнения происходит ступор. Консоль не на что не реагирует и ничего не выводит, если я в конце цикла раскомментирую cout. В общем, мне не ведома причина!

Comment: И на какой конкретно стоке происходит ступор? cout вообще не нужен

Comment: @VVT На 24-ой в коде и на 1-ой в файле. Какая-то ошибка в getline что ли? Хотя, у меня есть аналогичный код (только в файле слова разделены запятыми и идут одной строкой), где такая же конструкция исправно работает.

Comment: Дебагер вам в руки, и смотреть что происходит